# Creating Template in Xaml app for windows 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml

I am having a problem with creating template in a xaml app. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Pro in Windows 10. It's in the book "Head First C#". Previously, I've created the template but now it's creating problem. I guess something is missing. Here's a screenshot when I'm trying to create the template:

[image]

If I continue this way, I can't access my xaml tools from the document outline window because it has become a grid:

[image]

Comment: In your second screenshot, do you see the little icon with the upward facing arrow above the thick black line right next to where it has your template name `EnemyTemplate (ContentControl Template)` at the top of the Document Outline? Click that to exit template editing. When you're editing a template the Document Outline shows the DOM of the Template you're actively editing, which in this case is of type `ContentControl` named "EnemyTemplate"

Comment: Thanks bro... done! :)